# Can a bare 10 awg copper wire (ground for Starlink dish) be run underneath crawlspace w/o insulation?

Tags: crawlspace

Recently installed a Starlink dish 75 feet from house. Local electrician said I need to ground with 10 awg to the main service ground on opposite side of house, about 150 feet from dish. Bought the 10 awg stranded bare cable rated for direct burial,I'm ready to install, but now wondering if bare ground cable can run inside crawlspace or does it need to be insulated when in crawlspace?

Answer (score 3):

### It can be left bare

Insulation is not required for antenna grounding electrode conductors, as per NEC 810.21(B).

Answer (score 2):

According to The instructions the Ground rib on the cable satisfies UL requirements.  The NEC is satisfied when UL (or other testing lab) is satisfied.

But if you choose to supply additional bonding the Code says:

> **NEC 810.21  (A) Material** The bonding conductor or grounding electrode conductor shall be of copper, aluminum, copper-clad steel,
> copper-clad aluminum, bronze, or similar corrosion-resistant material.
> Aluminum or copper-clad aluminum bonding conductors or grounding
> electrode conductors shall not be used if subject to corrosive
> conditions or in direct contact with masonry or the earth or where
> subject to corrosive conditions. If used outside, aluminum or
> copper-clad aluminum conductors shall not be installed within 450 mm
> (18 in.) of the earth.
>
> **(B) Insulation** Insulation on bonding conductors or grounding electrode
> conductors shall not be required.